# Add new column with times same value was found in 2 columns

Tags: awk

Add new column with value of how many times the values in columns 1 and 2 contends exactly same value.

**input file**

```
46849,39785,2,012,023,351912.29,2527104.70,174.31
46849,39785,2,012,028,351912.45,2527118.70,174.30
46849,39785,3,06,018,351912.12,2527119.51,174.33
46849,39785,3,06,020,351911.80,2527105.83,174.40
46849,39797,2,012,023,352062.45,2527118.50,173.99
46849,39797,2,012,028,352062.51,2527105.51,174.04
46849,39797,3,06,020,352063.29,2527116.71,174.13,
46849,39809,2,012,023,352211.63,2527104.81,173.74
46849,39809,2,012,028,352211.21,2527117.94,173.69
46849,39803,2,012,023,352211.63,2527104.81,173.74
46849,39803,2,012,028,352211.21,2527117.94,173.69
46849,39801,2,012,023,352211.63,2527104.81,173.74
```

**Expected output file:**

```
4,46849,39785,2,012,023,351912.29,2527104.70,174.31
4,46849,39785,2,012,028,351912.45,2527118.70,174.30
4,46849,39785,3,06,018,351912.12,2527119.51,174.33
4,46849,39785,3,06,020,351911.80,2527105.83,174.40
3,46849,39797,2,012,023,352062.45,2527118.50,173.99
3,46849,39797,2,012,028,352062.51,2527105.51,174.04
3,46849,39797,3,06,020,352063.29,2527116.71,174.13,
2,46849,39809,2,012,023,352211.63,2527104.81,173.74
2,46849,39809,2,012,028,352211.21,2527117.94,173.69
2,46849,39803,2,012,023,352211.63,2527104.81,173.74
1,46849,39803,2,012,028,352211.21,2527117.94,173.69
1,46849,39801,2,012,023,352211.63,2527104.81,173.74
```

**attempt:**

```
awk -F, '{x[$1 $2]++}END{ for(i in x) {print i,x[i]}}' file

4684939785 4
4684939797 3
4684939801 1
4684939803 2
4684939809 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$1,$2]++
  next
}
{
  print a[$1,$2],$0
}
' Input_file Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** reading Input_file 2 times. Where first time I am creating an array named a with index of first and second field and counting their value on each occurrence too. On 2nd time file reading it printing count of the first 2 fields total and then printing while line.

One liner code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]++;next} {print a[$1,$2],$0}' Input_file Input_file
```

Comment: @OXXO, usually non-one liner codes are better to understand but as per your request I have added them now, lemme know if any queries here.